# exploding the 'other' slice in a google pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I can explode the first slice in a google pie chart using the options below.

```
        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          // set the slice threshold, slices below are all put in the 'Other' category.
          sliceVisibilityThreshold: .015,
          // explode the first (0) slice, I need to explode the 'Other' slice.
          slices: { 0: { offset: 0.5 } },
          is3D: true,
        };
```

My question is *how do I find the index of the 'other' slice to explode that?*
I am happy to do it programmatically after the chart is drawn. I tried -1 and 'other', but that doesn't work.

Obviously one needs to obtain the number of slices from the graph once the threshold calculation has been performed by the visualisation API.

Comment: Does not seem to be possible, only residue color and label are mentioned in the docs

Comment: I agree, do you want to post that as the answer, and I will happily accept it. I kind of got around the problem by rotating the pies and exploding some of the others. My problem is that 'other' takes up a very large part of the pies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to change the residue slice offset, or at least it does not say so in the documentation. There is an option to change `pieResidueSliceLabel` and `pieResidueSliceColor`, but no pieResidueSliceOffset

You could try playing around with `sliceVisibilityThreshold`, which sets the threshold for the slices that are grouped into others, but would need to make an issue to get a pieResidueSliceOffset option